# Where is the best place for storing user action in dashboard - CUSTOM PLUGIN

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins

I'm writing plugin which will store user action on dashboard. For example, when user publish or edit post I want to store this information in database, and display it in my plugin. I didn't write any plugins yet, so my question is where is the best place to store it? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: best way if you are creating a plugin is to create your own table and store info there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the first answer says, the best thing is to make use of the wp_posts and wp_postmeta table. That way you will have full access to the WP_Query and get_posts Wordpress calls.

You can add new posts using

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/

It is very easy to add and edit the information related to any post you add by using:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta

Using a custom table cab be a good idea but it's not always the best unless you need something very very specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can store that thing in wp_posts and postmeta  table also store post id and user id username.

That will easy to manage behalf of custom table..

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment on [@Andre M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598067/where-is-the-best-place-for-storing-user-action-in-dashboard-custom-plugin#answer-35599522), but I don't have enough reputation to do it.

To use `wp_insert_post` and `wp_update_post` and don't mess up with site posts and pages, the best way is building a custom post type. This link should help: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types